# Javascript: Combine Multiple Subscription Result into One Array

Tags: javascript, firebase, rxjs, subscription

I am trying to get data from one subscription and based on the data, I am calling nested subscription to add to the data object. This is how my function looks like:

```
this.subCatSubscription = this.afDatabase.list('/sub-categories/').snapshotChanges().subscribe((subCat: any) => {
      this.categories = [];
      subCat.forEach( sc => {
        if(sc.payload.val().category) {
          this.cat1Subscription = this.afDatabase.list('/categories/').snapshotChanges().subscribe((cat: any) => {
            cat.forEach(c => {
              if(c.key === sc.payload.val().category) {
                this.categories.push({ key: sc.key, ...sc.payload.val(), parentCatName: c.payload.val().name });
                //this.categories.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
              }
            });
          });
        } else {
          this.categories.push({ key: sc.key, ...sc.payload.val() });
          //this.categories.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
        }
        console.log(this.categories)
      });
    })
```

Is there any way to combine the two above subscription and get the desired data based on the condition I have?

Thanks.

Comment: Whenever I see a forEach I think of the forkJoin operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove the observables from your example, what you're trying to do is create an array of objects while some are mutated from a second array. What I've provided is the following steps.

1. Get sub-category data.
2. Create the array of default objects.
3. Get the parent category data.
4. For each sub-category that contains a parent match, mutate the object. Otherwise, return the object as is.

For step 3 (Get the parent category data) we can do this with a simple `switchMap()`.

```
  this.categories$ = this.afDatabase
    .list("/sub-categories")
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
        map(subCategories=>
            subCategories.map(sc=>({ key: sc.key, ...sc.payload.val() }))
        ),
        switchMap(categories=>this.afDatabase
            .list("/categories/")
            .snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
                map(parent=>
                    categories.map(c=>{
                        const match = parent.find(pc=>pc.key === c.category);
                        return !!match ? {...c, parentCatName: match.payload.val().name} : c
                    })
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Now, we're only requesting `/categores/` once instead of multiple times for each match.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a switchMap for that, since the second DB call depends on the first one.
So we can use the cancelling effect if the second request is pending and the first obervable emits again.

Keep in mind that nesting subscriptions is considered as an anti-pattern. You probably want to use mergeMap/flatMap or switchMap to achieve the same effect.

I would suggest something like this:

```
this.subCatSubscription = this.afDatabase.list('/sub-categories/').snapshotChanges()
.pipe(
  switchMap(subCat => {
    this.categories = [];
    return subCat.forEach( sc => {
      return sc.payload.val().category ? this.afDatabase.list('/categories/').snapshotChanges() : empty()
    });
  })
).subscribe(console.log)
```

Probably this code is not perfect (not sure if we need that double return), I cannot test it right now, but I hope it helps.